# C# DataGridView values read failure

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

We are facing a weird issue in C#.

We have a WinForms application running on .NET 3.5 SP1.

When the grid is being read in the loop, the code fails to read the values in the row. This behavior is intermittent. The failure is around 20% of the times.

The code is really, simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].Value == null || dgv.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
         // PROBLEM!!!
         continue;
    }
}
```

When the program runs, we could see the grid populated. Our client has sent us the picture with grid populated but values showing null. When values are null, we added a debug code to show a message box.

This condition is getting hit:

```
dgv.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].Value == null
```

This has happened on 2 different Win 7 based PCs in production. Not reproduced inhouse. Any pointers would be really helpful.

**Solution**
Finally we have got the solution to this issue. The issue was resolved on adding CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler

```
private void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Now that it is resolved, it still perplexes us as to why a simple GridView would require adding this kind of event. Any thoughts on that would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried with String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].Value), but i am not sure about the cause for your issue

Comment: where do the values come from?

Comment: No. We did not try using String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].Value). The values are entered by the user by typing and then clicking on Save. The Save function fails to detect those values.

Comment: I have added the solution we found to this issue. If someone could explain why the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event is required for a standard gridview, it will be of great help. Thank you!